# next.js environment variables are undefined ("next": "13.1.6")

Tags: typescript, next.js, environment-variables, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I know that this has been asked before, but none of the answers solved my problem.

I'm trying to use env variables in next j's with typescript, but I get this error:

> An argument of type "string | undefined" cannot be assigned to the parameter of type "string".
> Type 'undefined' cannot be assigned to type 'string.

My env variable is named: `NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGODB_URI` and the `.env` file is in the root directory of my project

I'm using it in a file called db.ts which is in is in /my-project/utils/db.ts like this:

```
import mongoose, { ConnectionStates } from 'mongoose';

interface IConnection {
  isConnected: ConnectionStates | null;
}
const connection: IConnection = {
  isConnected: null
};

async function connect() {
  if (connection.isConnected !== null) {
    console.log('already connected');
    return;
  }
  if (mongoose.connections.length > 0) {
    connection.isConnected = mongoose.connections[0].readyState;
    if (connection.isConnected === 1) {
      console.log('use previous connection');
      return;
    }
    await mongoose.disconnect();
  }
  const db = mongoose.connect(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGODB_URI);
}
```

Comment: did you reload your app ?

Comment: yes forgot to add that, i even closed and open vscode and nothing

Comment: Where in your project are you storing your environment variable? Make sure you've killed the NextJS server and restarted it after adding an environment variable.

Comment: the env variables are in the .env file in the root directorty of my project, and i did restarted the server

Comment: Try without NEXT_PUBLIC prefix, if is moongose maybe you are calling the util inside api router, api routes can't access to public envs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not "next.js environment variables are undefined" issue. Since you have prefixed `NEXT_PUBLIC` you can access that env variable on both experimental app directory or regular client side directory. the error is about typescript. you have to cast it with `as string`

```
const db = mongoose.connect(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGODB_URI as string);
```

if you `console.log("dada", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGODB_URI)` on app directory file you should see the log on terminal, or in client side directory file, you could see the log the on the browser terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to access the environment variable in client component you should add `NEXT_PUBLIC_` i.e. the name will be start from `NEXT_PUBLIC_`